# IOS Xamarin forms button works in the simulator but will not work on the iphone

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin forms IOS app that runs great in the simulator but when installed on my iphone none of the buttons work. I have app center debugging in there so I can see it never even gets into the button logic. After reading some posts, I even pulled the button out and put it into a separate frame to ensure nothing was overlaying it, but that did nothing. I could really use some help.

Here is my xaml

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ViewMode:EnterCarViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<Grid BackgroundColor="Purple">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="47"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="65"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="105"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="85"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="65"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Frame BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="10" CornerRadius="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Row="0">
        <Label Text="Enter Car" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="25" />
    </Frame>
    <Label Text="{Binding EntError}" BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Red" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" FontSize="20" />
    <Label Text="Year:" TextColor="White" FontSize="Medium" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" />
    <Entry Text="{Binding EntYear}" Keyboard="Numeric" BackgroundColor="White" TextColor="Black"  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
        <Entry.Behaviors>
            <Validate:MaxLengthValidator  MaxLength="4"/>
        </Entry.Behaviors>
    </Entry>
    <Label Text="Name:" TextColor="White" FontSize="Medium" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Margin="6"/>
    <Entry Text="{Binding EntName}" TextColor="Black" Keyboard="Default" BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="6" >
        <Entry.Behaviors>
            <Validate:MaxLengthValidator  MaxLength="30"/>
        </Entry.Behaviors>
    </Entry>
    <Label Text="Default:" TextColor="White" FontSize="Medium" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <Switch IsToggled="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="7" IsVisible="true"/>
    <Frame BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="10" CornerRadius="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="9">
        <Button x:Name="MyButton" Command="{Binding AddCarData}" IsEnabled="True"  Text="Add Car" BackgroundColor="Yellow" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" TextColor="Black"/>
    </Frame>
</Grid>
```

The corresponding method in my viewModel is as follows;

```
    public Command AddCarData => new Command(() =>
    {
        Analytics.TrackEvent("Top of AddCarData. EntYear = " + EntYear + " EntName = " + EntName);

        bool errorFound = false;
        IsVisibleLabel = false;
        IsVisibleResults = false;
        if (EntYear == string.Empty || EntYear == null)
        {
            IsVisibleLabel = true;
            EntError = "You Must Enter Year";
            errorFound = true;
        }
        else if (!errorFound)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[1-9]\d{3,}$");
            Match match = regex.Match(EntYear);
            if (!match.Success && !errorFound)
            {
                IsVisibleLabel = true;
                EntError = "Year Must Be 4 Numbers";
                errorFound = true;
            }
            else if ((Convert.ToInt32(EntYear) < 1900) && !errorFound)
            {
                IsVisibleLabel = true;
                EntError = "You Must Enter a Car Name";
                errorFound = true;
            }
        }
        if (EntName == null && !errorFound)
        {
            IsVisibleLabel = true;
            EntError = "You Must Enter a Car Name";
            errorFound = true;
        }

        Analytics.TrackEvent("In AddCarData. errorFound = " + errorFound);

        if (!errorFound)
        {
            var isDefault = false;
            if (IsChecked)
            {
                isDefault = true;
            }
            else
            {
                isDefault = false;
            }
            MileageItemRepository repository = new MileageItemRepository();
            if (IsChecked)
            {
                var autoResults = repository.GetAuto2();
                foreach (var item in autoResults)
                {
                    if (item.IsDefault)
                    {
                        var resp = repository.UpdateAutoAsync(false, item.Id);
                    }
                }
                App.Current.Properties["processedChange"] = false;
            }
            AutoTableDefination data = new AutoTableDefination()
            {
                IsDefault = isDefault,
                CarYear = EntYear,
                CarDesc = EntName
            };

            int results = repository.AddAutoData(data).Result;

            Analytics.TrackEvent("In AddCarData Results from AddAutoData. results = " + results);

            if (results == 1)
            {
                IsVisibleResults = true;
                EntResults = "Entered Successfully";
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(App.Current.Properties["firstAutoEntered"]))
                {
                    App.Current.Properties["autoId"] = 1;
                    App.Current.Properties["firstAutoEntered"] = false;
                }

                var nav = MyNavigation.GetNavigation();
                nav.PushAsync(new UpdateCars());
            }
            else
            {
                IsVisibleResults = true;
                EntResults = "Error, Please Try Again";
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: a couple of random thoughts.  1) the Button is not a child of the Grid, so setting the Row/Col/etc values on it is pointless.  2) try replacing the Command with a simple Clicked handler and see if that fires.  3) try using a traditional get for the body of the Command instead of an expression body

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I am sorry, but I am not sure what you mean by a "traditional get for the body of the Command instead of an expression body", Can you elaborate a little. Thanks so much!

Comment: `public ICommand AddCarData { get; set; }`

Comment: I knew I could replace the command button with a click handler, but did not want to do that as I did not know how to get the data from the view code behind to the view model, but I found out how to do that and yet, the click event works just fine. So, my button is like this,
    <Button Clicked="AddCarData"
and the way I get my data out of the button event is as follows
     Button button = (Button)sender;
            var imt = (Grid)button.Parent.Parent;
            var c = (Entry)imt.Children[3];
            var EntYear = c.Text;

Comment: the button event handler can still access the properties and methods of the VM